# Emulator in AMD Processor is not working

Tags: android-emulator

I using AMD processor. I have installed everything related to eclipse perfectly. But I'm unable to start the emulator. program is hang and keep waiting for adb forever. The same issue in android studio also. Please give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Android Studio on an HP x360, which is a nice little laptop but has a puny processor:). I spent ages getting the Intel Hax virtual machine thingy installed on my machine, as well as configuring bios (which I found AVAST blocked changes to, so had to uninstall it).

After probably hours this week (I'm new to Android) waiting for the emulator to do it's thing, start up, load program, and eat memory, I decided to plug in my phone (Moto-e).

This has made a massive improvement! Only takes a minute to compile and run now! You also have piece of mind that your app will run in the real world.

So as a newb to Android, I'd say don't bother with the emulator.... plug a real device in.

See here for setting up HAXM, if you have trouble installing, it may be antivirus etc blocking it....

[Intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=amd%20virtualization)

All the best.

try these threads [Virtualization threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=amd%20virtualization)

Comment: Doh! Just realised you're using AMD processor.